# How do I stop a batch file retaining control of the command line

Tags: windows, batch-file

Basically I wrote a very very simple batch script to shorten the opening of Notepad++. It accepts a single argument which it passes to Notepad++. The file is named npp.bat and is located in System32 and contains the commands:

```
@ECHO off
Notepad++ %1
```

As you can see, extremely simple, but it works as intended. However this is the first case I've had where a batch file retains control of the command line. It doesn't allow any more input until Notepad++ closes.

Basically what I'm wondering is if there is a Windows equivalent of the ampersand (&) operator in Linux

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put start at the end!

```
@ECHO off
start "X" Notepad++ %1
```

start launches programs (and documents, and URLs) in a separate process

the "X" paramter is not actually needed in this example.  start takes the first parameter if it's a quoted string as a window title for console applications, so if your are trying to run a command with spaces in the  file name has spaces it'll get quotes and start has to see find something else first or it will steal the filename.

If you do `start "c:\users\yourself\documents and settings\test one.doc"` start will open a cmd window with the title `c:\users\yourself\documents and settings\test one.doc` instead of opening the document,  `start "X" "c:\users\yourself\documents and settings\test one.doc"` will open the document.

Comment: Thank you Jasen this worked correctly :) could you please explain the start "X"? Just curiosity at this stage.

Comment: have eedited the answer, do `start /?` for more info.